# Setting up traefik with docker services on aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm, traefik

I'm trying to use traefik in fron't of my docker services (although only 1 docker service to start with) I've been able to set-up traefik however it is ignoring the labels that I include in my docker compose file. I'm using a docker swarm on AWS.

The log indicates 
`"Filtering container without port and no traefik.port label service_myapp.3"`

I've inspected both the service, and a the containers, using `docker service inspect` and `docker container inspect` and the labels are present.

The  traefik web console shows a docker tab, but with nothing under it.

Here is my traefik.toml

```
logLevel = "DEBUG"
traefikLogsFile = "/var/logs/traefik.log"

[entryPoints]
    [entryPoints.http]
    address = ":80"
[web]
address = ":8080"

[docker]
endpoint = "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
domain = "docker.localhost"
watch = true
swarmmode = true
exposedbydefault = false
```

and here is my docker compose yml

```
version: "3.4"
configs:
  traefik:
    external:
      name: traefik
services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:1.3.5
    configs:
      - source: traefik
        target: /etc/traefik/traefik.toml
        mode: 0400
    depends_on:
      - myapp
    volumes:
      - traefiklogs:/var/logs
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
      - 8080:8080
    networks:
      - public
      - private
    tty: true
    deploy:
      mode: global
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.role == manager
  myapp:
    image: myapp
    deploy:
      endpoint_mode: vip
      replicas: 3
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
    ports:
      - "4000:8080"
    networks:
      - public
      - private
    labels:
      traefik.frontend.rule: "Host:myapp.myapp.com"
      traefik.backend: "myapp"
      traefik.docker.network=: "public"
      traefik.enable: "true"
      traefik.port: "4000"
networks:
  public:
    driver_opts:
      encrypted: 1
  private:
    driver_opts:
      encrypted: 1
volumes:
  sqldata:
  traefiklogs:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `swarmmode = true`, you need to set the labels on the service instead of the containers. That's done by defining the labels within the `deploy` section:

```
version: "3.4"
configs:
  traefik:
    external:
      name: traefik
services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:1.3.5
    configs:
      - source: traefik
        target: /etc/traefik/traefik.toml
        mode: 0400
    depends_on:
      - myapp
    volumes:
      - traefiklogs:/var/logs
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
      - 8080:8080
    networks:
      - public
      - private
    tty: true
    deploy:
      mode: global
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.role == manager
  myapp:
    image: myapp
    deploy:
      endpoint_mode: vip
      replicas: 3
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
      labels:
        traefik.frontend.rule: "Host:myapp.myapp.com"
        traefik.backend: "myapp"
        traefik.docker.network=: "public"
        traefik.enable: "true"
        traefik.port: "4000"
    ports:
      - "4000:8080"
    networks:
      - public
      - private
networks:
  public:
    driver_opts:
      encrypted: 1
  private:
    driver_opts:
      encrypted: 1
volumes:
  sqldata:
  traefiklogs:
```